# Copy all contents of all files in a directory with a certain suffix

Tags: perl, command-line

I have a bunch of directories named project1, project2, etc.

In those folders are a bunch of perl files (extension ".pl").

Basically, I want to just copy the contents of those .pl files into a new file, let's call it "everything.txt".

Can someone help me out with this? I really don't care which programming language it's done in, although I'd prefer something commandline. But perl, python, and Java would work too.

**Edit:** Also, there are some duplicate names, which shouldn't be a problem given I just want to write their contents out to a file, but just thought I'd let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bash: `cat project*/*.pl > everything.txt`

Answer (score 1):

In Unix-y systems:

```
find project1 project2 ... -name \*.pl -exec cat {} \; > everything.txt
```

To make, say, a proper `.tar` archive file that will let you recover the original file names and permissions:

```
tar cf everything.txt.tar $(find project1 project2 ... -name \*.pl)
```

(The `$(...)` syntax requires the `bash` shell).